# html5 video not playing on mobile browser

Tags: android, html, video, browser

I have this code to play a video on a mobile web browser, but it does not autoplay.

can anyone suggest ways to make this work on Android devices?

```
<video id="vidone" name="vidone" autoplay poster="eh5v.files/html5video/testx.jpg" style="width:100%" title="testx" preload='true'>
<source src="eh5v.files/html5video/testx.m4v" />
<source src="eh5v.files/html5video/testx.webm" type="video/webm" />
<source src="eh5v.files/html5video/testx.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
</video>
```

This works on regular browsers and mobile browser simulators, but not on the actual device, I have tried multiple javascript options and still no code that works.

Answer (score 0):

Autoplay on mobile devices is generally switched off by the manufacturers to avoid users racking up huge costs in downloading videos that autoplay.

This is a good thing.

You can't, and shouldn't, do anything about it.